# Use same webdriver instance

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

I am trying to use the same webdriver instance with multiple websites. Each website is being called by a WinForm button.
The purpose of this is to make the app run faster.

**THE CODE**

```
public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        public IWebDriver driverON;
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("C:\App\ChromeDriver");
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.BinaryLocation = "C:\App\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe";
            IWebDriver driverON = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
        }
        public void Repartizare()
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driverON;
            driverON.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://ipadress/abc/");
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByName('day')[0].value = ''");
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByName('month')[0].value = ''");
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByName('year')[0].value = ''");
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByName('btnPrint')[0].click()");
        }
        public void Registry()
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driverON;
            driverON.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://ipadress/def/");
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByName('type')[0].value = 'object'");
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByName('btnPrint')[0].click()");
        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Repartizare();
        }
        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Registry();
        }
    }
```

At the first occurence of the `driverOn` in the `Repartizare` or `Registry`function I get this error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I have to get the driverON from `Form5()` into these functions. What am I missing?
I have found some tutorials on the internet but they talk mostly about multiple classes hypotheses in java language and I don't know how to adapt them form my usage.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Form5 method, you are doing it wrong.

Change this:

```cs
IWebDriver driverON = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

to this:

```cs
driverON = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```